# dynamic building of keys in node mongoose javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am an intermediate to node js.

I have a mongoose schema that consists of various fields as below

```
result_1
result_2
result_3
result_4
result_5
```

The data will be received in numeric (1-5) as the result number and accordingly have to generate the key, eg,

we have result number in a variable

```
var result = 2;

var field = "result_" + result;
```

What I want to achieve is when I update using `findOneAndUpdate` I want to use the field variable as key.

```
Learner.findOneAndUpdate({ nrc: traffic.code_nrc }, {
    field: val
traffic.code_test_result
}, function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      }
});
```

Let me know if what I am trying to do is something very orthodox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `Learner.findOneAndUpdate({ nrc: traffic.code_nrc }, {
    ['result_' + result]: val
},...`

Comment: @Veeram The solution didnt work.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? `Learner.findOneAndUpdate({ nrc: traffic.code_nrc }, { [field]: val },...`

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that mongoose doesn't allow you to do that, you can use this little loop hole:

```
var update={};
update[field] = value;
Learner.findOneAndUpdate({nrc: traffic.code_nrc},update,function(err,res){
if(err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: didnt work with my case as I want the field parameter to be dynamic...